# HTTP CONNECT request body is reduced to / when proxying through Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, tunneling

I am using Apache 2.2.15 as a reverse-proxy running on Scientific Linux 6. It is being used to connect an application to a remote server, where the application being connected to requires that the CONNECT request comes through with the body intact.

The proxy receives the connection correctly:

```
CONNECT <destinationhost>:6220 HTTP/1.1
```

But the destination server receives this:

```
[17/Jun/2014:15:01:13 +0200] "CONNECT / HTTP/1.1" 400 346 "-" "-"
```

So somewhere inside the proxy the CONNECT body is "stripped"? All other request methods work just fine, problems surface only when using CONNECT. This happens both with TLS and without. All headers seem to go through correctly.

My proxy configuration is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://destinationhost:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://destinationhost:8082/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried the directive "AllowCONNECT 6220" and proxying using RewriteRules, but they don't seem to make a difference.

The results are the same with a simple telnet test, and when using Apache running on my local Ubuntu machine as the proxy. So is this normal behaviour for CONNECT, and the problem is actually the application running at the destination, expecting a "malformed" CONNECT request?

If not, what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you describe your situation (what you're trying to accomplish) and ProxyPass configuration a bit more?

Comment: I have added some details.